# appengine toy program hitting quota limits for reads and writes

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore, gae-quotas

Let's say I wanted to make an appengine application that stores a 50,000 word dictionary and also equivalent dictionaries in 10 other languages of similar size.

I got this working locally on my dev server, but when I went to load the first dictionary into the real appserver I immediately went over my writes per day quota.  I had no idea how many dictionary entries made it into the datastore.  So, 24 hours later, I went and tried to bulk download the dictionary and see how many entries I actually had, but doing that I hit the reads per day quota and got nothing back for my trouble.  I tried enabling billing at setting a daily maximum of $1.00 and hit that quota through the bulkloader and didn't get any data for my trouble or my $1.00.

Anyway, so I looked at my datastore viewer and it shows that each of my dictionary words required 8 writes to the datastore.

So, does this mean that this sort of application is inappropriate for appengine?  Should I not be trying to store a dictionary in there?  Is there a smarter way to do this?  For instance, could I store the dictionary in file form in the blob store somehow and then do things with it programatically from there?

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that you'll be reading much less then writing so the problem is getting the data in, not so much reading it.

So all you need to do to use your current configuration is to slow down the write rate. Then, presumably you'll be getting each word by it's ID (the word itself I hope!) and so reads will be fast and small, exactly as you want.

You could do this: Chop your source data into 1 file per letter . Upload those files with your application and create a task to read each file in turn then slowly write that data to the datastore. Once that task completes, it's last action is to call the next task.

It might take a week to complete but once it's there it'll be alot more handy then an opaque blob you have to get from the blob store, reading N words for every single 1 you are actually interested in,  and then unpack and process for every word.

You can also use the bulk downloader to upload data as well!

Comment: I like this, thank you.  Glad to know that this is doable.  I was afraid I would hear something like "you can't do that" or the like.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Actually it was the bulkloader.py that I was using that I hit the quota with so fast, but I like the idea of scripting it into small batches that run unattended and maybe taking a week, but at least it could be done.  thx

Comment: Might be possible to do something with backends, they can run for about ~9 hours a day for free but can run tasks that take a long time so might be useful here depending on how you want to go about it. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/

Comment: also if you use NDB and get by key that'll be cached automatically for you.

Comment: Now that I've started banging my head against this wall, I wonder how all this compares to Amazon pricing...

Comment: I found I could remove one field from my dictionary and reduce it to 6 writes per entry.  Doing the math roughly ... if I want to house 10 languages at approx 50K entries each. at 6 writes per word, that's around 3M writes or about 101 days at 8K words per upload or $3 with billing assuming no errors. 30 languages would take upwards of a year at 8k every 24 hours or $10 with billing and no upload errors...

Comment: nevermind, it's still 8 writes per entry, even with only 3 fields per entry

Comment: If you write via remote_api your self you have absolute control on your write frequency, a the update process is run locally.

Comment: How are you measuring the number of writes per entity ?

Comment: Well, on my dev server, I'm just looking at the the datastore viewer which is showing my entries and there is a column that says Write Ops and they all show 8 in that column.

Comment: might be worth checking it out with appstats too. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats